# Loop through a list of urls in a text file

Tags: shell

I have a list of URL's that looks like the following:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QVgFCCQWBOs
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8TrMhR7ZpBk
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ctAvtBJB3s
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xTB79UdZahU
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GjTlEM99rv8
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XRdUgPGsj3k
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_700uBiNv-A
```

Every url is on a newline. I want to execute a command involving each url like so:

`ytdl "<one url>" -a`

I essentially want to run the command one using each url present in the text file. Is this possible with a shell script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I have done:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo '---------------------------------------------'
echo 'Now downloading all videos from videoList.txt'
echo '---------------------------------------------'


while read p;
  do   ytdl "$p" -a;
done < videoList.txt

echo '---------------------------------------------'
echo 'Completed downloading all videos in the list'
echo '---------------------------------------------'


echo '---------------------------------------------'
echo 'Moving .m4a and .ogg files to correct folder'
echo '---------------------------------------------'
mv *.m4a ~/Music/youtubeDownloads/
mv *.ogg ~/Music/youtubeDownloads/
```

Answer (score 1):

Use GNU Parallel:

```
parallel ytdl {} -a :::: urlfile
```

To learn more watch the intro videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1 and spend an hour walking through the tutorial http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html Your command line will love you for it.

Comment: Never quite figured out the syntax. Can you explain what the `::::` means? After all, you'd be in the best position to do so.

Comment: Watch the intro videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1 and spend an hour walking through the tutorial http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Comment: I see that you are the author of said tool. Does this serve advantageous over the method I have posted?

Comment: It is shorter. It runs in parallel.